# What is the meaning of the CastStatusCodes 2255?

Tags: android, google-cast

I have an Android sender app and Android TV receiver app. When I start to connect the Android TV receiver app, it returns an error code 2255 in `onSessionStartFailed()`.

I have referred the Google Cast documentation (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes) and cannot found the definition of 2255 in this page.

Also, I try to read the code from `com.google.android.gms.cast.CastStatusCodes`, it seems that error code 2255 is a special case.

```
if (var0 < 2300) {
  return String.format(Locale.ROOT, "Cast remote display status code %d", var0);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue, but this can happen if you try to run the [Cast Debug Logger](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging/cast_debug_logger) on a non-google receiver hardware.

As it says:

> Warning: Make sure to change setEnabled to false for a production receiver.

Properly disabling it in prod fixed the issue for me. But, man, it's so bad that error codes are not properly documented. There are several other that can also be thrown for various reasons that are undocumented.

What was actually happening for me is the CAF library was throwing an exception because it is trying to load the debug logger, but the debug logger is not supported on non-google hardware. This caused the VM to not launch properly and so it started throwing remote display errors.

If that is not your issue, you should try to log in to the back-end if your device if possible and download an error log. Sometimes that can highlight what is happening. I don't know if it's possible to crash the VM in other ways, but it might be and the error log might show why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate that status code into a reason code to get a description of the error. You can do that by calling.

`CastContext.getSharedInstance(context).getCastReasonCodeForCastStatusCode(statusCode)`

The docs for the error reasons are [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastReasonCodes)
2255 translates into reason code 6, which is `CAST_SOCKET_ERROR`.