# What is CastStatusCode 2252?

Tags: google-play-services, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

The `onEnded` event when ending a cast session on an Android device has given me a status code of 2252. I don't see this code documented anywhere [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes). Does anyone know the root cause of this code?

Comment: I only found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65774111/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-caststatuscodes-2255 for another 225x code. The only suggestion there is to disable `CastDebugLogger`. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Yeah I saw that one as well @dratenik. Since they have the same first 3 digits I thought maybe it would be related but I'm not using a CastDebugLogger afaik. Thanks anyway! Gonna have to agree with the answerer on that post though: "man, it's so bad that error codes are not properly documented"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will provide a new class in the next upcoming release that can help with the CastStatusCode to map them. This release is expected to go out next week. Please do join the google group to get the release updates. https://developers.google.com/cast/support#news_and_announcements

And also once the release is out you can see release notes here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes

Comment: Added CastReasonCodes to provide detailed explanations of CastStatusCodes. Use the CastContext#getCastReasonCodeForCastStatusCode(int) method to translate from CastStatusCodes to CastReasonCodes. Please see more details about the release here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes#april-20,-2021